# ListView Change Icon On Hover/Focus

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I'm using a navigation drawer now, and that all works fine. I'm using a selector to change the text color and background color on hover/focus, but how can I change my icon so it will turn white, and when it's not focussed / hovered. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you please show the code, what you have done for it?